# CUDA and CuDNN version conflict against Tensorflow2.4.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-20.04

I'd like someone to give your TF2.4.1 environment with RTX 30X0.
More specific, I'd like to know nvidia driver, CUDA and CuDNN versions. Also TF2.4.1 installation manner after all.

I am struggling to install tensorflow2.4.1 into my PC which has below.
OS : Ubuntu 20.04 (Version does not matter)
CPU: Ryzen 5600X
GPU: RTX 3070

I know that the requirements from TF2.4.1 is CUDA11.0 w/ CuDNN8.0.4 according to following site.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

However, NVIDIA driver version 457 is the first version for RTX 3070 and current latest version is Ver.460. So, I installed version 460 and 'nvidia-smi' returns following on terminal. (The CUDA version 11.2 is NOT installed with this driver installation, as you may know.)

| NVIDIA-SMI 460.73.01    Driver Version: 460.73.01    CUDA Version: 11.2     |

The support matrices from NVIDIA site below says that CUDA 11.0 is for driver ver.450. Which means that it cannot be the one for RTX 3070. For RTX 3070, I think CUDA 11.2 or later is the one since it supports Ver.460.

https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/support-matrix/index.html

After installation of CUDA11.2 w/ CuDNN8.1.0, I installed tensorflow by pip to pyenv. However, the TF runs on CPU. I confirmed by 'tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')' which returned '[]'
as I expected.
As long as TF2.4.1's restriction with regard to NVIDIA environment is effective, do you think I cannot make TF environment on this PC?

I tried so many patterns with fresh installation of Ubuntu. Once I failed to install ver.450 with DPKG error, but I will try again.

Comment: You can user a newer driver with an older CUDA toolkit. There is no restriction there,

Comment: Thank you for your reply in such a short notice. I installed CUDA11.0 after driver ver.460 installation, but during the CUDA installation, many errors having word '450' in there happened. That made me believe that CUDA11.0 requires only ver.450. Anyway I'll reinstall Ubuntu and try ver.450 installation. I'll make a comment of the result.

Comment: `CUDA Toolkit 11.3` comes with a compatible driver. Anything preventing from using it?

Comment: Thank you, Lukasz. Like I posted, TF2.4.1 only works on CUDA11.0. Today, I tried it on CUDA11.2, but TF only worked with CPU and It did not use RTX 3070. As you may know, old TF2 kept working on CUDA10.1, no matter which CUDA version was the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all. I found that my issue is solved as below.

After Ubuntu 20.04 installed, install the latest NVIDIA driver.
(Maybe no need, since it will be installed automatically with CUDA installation.)

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nvidia-driver-460
nvidia-smi
sudo reboot
```

Install CUDA11.0 which TF2.4.1 wants.
This time I refer runfile[local] instead of deb[local] which I got failure before.
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.0-update1-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=2004&target_type=runfilelocal

```
sudo apt update
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.0.3/local_installers/cuda_11.0.3_450.51.06_linux.run
sudo sh cuda_11.0.3_450.51.06_linux.run
```

*WARNING *‘Existing package manager installation of the driver found.’* appeared at above line and I aborted it. Done below instead.

```
sudo sh ./cuda_11.0.3_450.51.06_linux.run --toolkit --silent –-override
```

Confirm if  usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin exists and edit bashrc.

```
sudo vim ~/.bashrc
```

Add following 2 lines to bashrc.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

reload bashrc

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Install CuDNN. Download a tared library in advance.
https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive

```
cd Downloads
tar -xzvf cudnn-11.0-linux-x64-v8.0.4.30.tgz
sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda/include
sudo cp -P cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
sudo apt update
```

Install TF2.4.1 as https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?hl=ja instructs.

```
sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip python3-venv
cd Documents/ML/tf-test1
python3 -m venv test1
source test1/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip list
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Check if TF is properly installed.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
print(tf.test.gpu_device_name())
```

When I perform my CNN model, ‘Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize’ occurred as fit(). Then I did below as always.

`export TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH=true`

Then sorted out.

Comment: it worked for ubuntu 20.10, which i was struck for 3 days.

Comment: If someone wants to remove previous mess use `sudo apt-get --purge remove 'cuda*'`
`sudo apt-get --purge remove 'nvidia*'`
`sudo apt-get --purge remove 'libnvidia*'`

Answer (score 0):

I have an ubuntu 20.4 like you. But so that tensorflow can see the GPUs well, what finally worked for me is:
tensorflow-gpu 2.2.0
cuda 10.1
cudnn 7.6
And all with an NVIDIA drive of version 460.73.01

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. In this case, one of the important facter is Ampere architecture GPU like RTX 30X0 series. Is your PC equipped with RTX 30X0 series?
I have one more PC with GTX 1070 which has TF2.2 on CUDA10.1. It working very well.

Comment: I have an rtx 2060 ... But the configurations I saw it on a github comment which was massively voted on. Myself I had too much trouble before I came across this one.

Comment: I can totally relate to you. When I set up the current PC with GTX1070, it was nightmare. One of the reason is that It was 4 years ago, so there was less info in Japanese site. Anyway, I think I find the solution with this RTX 3070 w/ CUDA11.0 and ver.460. I'll post what I did tomorrow. Thx.